# Are there any effective multilevel mob grinders in 1.2.5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I've seen some of these super high efficiency traps (> 50,000 items/hour) but most of them seem not to work on 1.2.5.

What I was hoping would work would be floors that spawn and let the mobs drop through via pistons (6 blocks that move to the left, pause, then move to the right) but this seems not to work on bukkit.

Comment: Why don't they work?

Comment: @fredley: I have a feeling that updates to mob pathfinding broke a number of designs.  Ledges lined with signs, for instance, don't seem to be effective like they used to (based on the spawning tower I recently built in creative, with some help from MCEdit).

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is the following:

- Arrange a large tower of rings that are 1 block wide, separated by 3 blocks vertically:

```
####
#  #
#  #
#  #
#  #
#  #
####
```

- Surround the ring with Pistons facing inward. Place pressure plates on the ring itself, so that stepping on the pressure plate activates the piston and pushes you (or the mob) into the center
- Make sure gaps are filled so that mobs can only spawn directly on the pressure plates.
- Make the stack of rings as high as you can
- *Bonus step for exp farms: Work out which height drop will cause mobs to lose all but half a heart of damage. Place creepers within the ring here, and place no spawning rings below this level. This way all mobs will drop the same amount and end up with half a heart and can be easily harvested for exp.*
- Plumb in the base of the trap as normal with water/lava to kill mobs and collect items
- ????
- #### Profit

I've made a small version to test the concept, it seems to work ok. [Download my schematic](http://tommedley.com/files/grinder.schematic) and try it out for yourself.

Here's a very detailed tutorial of making an enderman/exp variant:

Comment: *Place creepers within the ring here* - do you mean vines, or the actual green exploding monsters?

Comment: @Konerak Which do you think? :-P I mean *creeper vines*, which act like ladders and 'reset' the fall speed of the falling mobs so that they always take exactly the same amount of fall damage.

Comment: Why rings?  How big can/should the rings be to maximize efficiency?  Endermen in The End are a special case.  What about regular mobs in the overworld?

Answer (score 0):

This one works for 1.2.5 and gets 10,000/per hour...
its the best I have seen so far in 1.2.5.

Comment: Hi Leafygreen19, welcome to the site. Could you summarize the contents of the video so that if it goes down for some reason we still have a good answer?

Comment: i'm pretty sure that's the method that doesn't work on smp :\

Comment: a bit big for me